# Override abstract method TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have abstract method:

```
abstract setProp<T, K extends keyof T>(value: keyof T, key: K);
```

I tried to override this in class heir:

```
public setProp<IParentProfile, K extends keyof IParentProfile>(value: keyof IParentProfile, key: K) {
    this.model[key] = value;
  }
```

But interpretation says me an error:

Incompatible override method from abstract class, where did I make mistake?

Also I tried this way:

```
abstract setProp<T, K extends keyof T>(model: T, value: keyof T, key: K): T;
```

And using:

```
public setProp<IParentProfile, K extends keyof IParentProfile>(model: IParentProfile, value: keyof IParentProfile, key: K) {
    return model[key] = value;
  }
```

Can you see why this does [not work please](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IParentProfile%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fullname%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20school%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20email%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20phone%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20document%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20number%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20birhday%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20day%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20month%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20year%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20private%20model%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20setProp%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(value%3A%20any%2C%20key%3A%20K)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.model%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Aa.setProp%3CIParentProfile%3E('O'%2C%20'fullname')%3B)

Comment: Hmm, seems like a compiler bug to me (but who knows).  Here's a more [minimal reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20m%3CT%2C%20U%20extends%20T%3E%28t%3A%20T%2C%20u%3A%20U%29%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20m%3CT%2C%20U%20extends%20T%3E%28t%3A%20T%2C%20u%3A%20U%29%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: Can you check my link in questin

Comment: In your link you didn't provide any type for K

Comment: Why K is a keys of T, but T I provide

Comment: yes but you need to provide it like a.setProp<IParentProfile, 'fullname'>('O', 'fullname'); so if you update for a.setProp<IParentProfile, 'fullname'>('O', 'id'); it won't compile

Comment: I want to know why this doesn't work.  If someone official/knowledgeable doesn't answer and if you don't open an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) about this, I might.  Good luck.

Comment: Hm, wondering, then I need to set this twice, awful code

Comment: for your case you could change to public setProp<T>(value: any, key: keyof T): T

Comment: Do you mean set value as `any`? But I want ensure that value is compatible with type of property T

Comment: @OPV I wish you'd ask one question per question.  The code in your link is a different issue; you want to [partially specify type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23696), which should be available in [TypeScript 3.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#30-july-2018).

Comment: I filed [Microsoft/TypeScript#25373](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25373) to get an answer about this.

Comment: Can you attach me there to issue, like a author?

Comment: I can't change ownership of the issue, but you can of course subscribe to notifications or comment on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, it looks like a compiler bug. (This is only addressing the inability to override your generic method, not the code you added in the link later.)

The following is currently an error in TypeScript 2.9 and below:

```
class A {
  m<T, U extends T>(t: T, u: U) { }
}

class B extends A {
  m<T, U extends T>(t: T, u: U) { }
//^--error, T is not assignable to T
}
```

It seems that you can't override a generic method if its [generic constraints use type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints).

I filed [Microsoft/TypeScript#25373](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25373) and it has (as of 2018-07-02) been classified as a bug, which is slated to be addressed in TypeScript 3.1.

---

Until then, I guess you need to use workarounds.  Actually, the only workaround I can find that lets you override `abstract` generic methods using type-parameter constraints is the [sledgehammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sledgehammer) of workarounds, the [`@tsignore` comment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments):

```
class A {
  m<T, U extends T>(t: T, u: U) { }
}

class B extends A {
  // @ts-ignore
  m<T, U extends T>(t: T, u: U) { } // no error
}
```

I don't normally recommend using `@ts-ignore`, because all it does is suppress the error output; it doesn't magically fix anything.  But assuming the compiler bug gets fixed in the near future, it's a reasonable temporary fix.

Hope that helps; good luck!